# Writing to file with unwanted empty lines

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that's removing some unwanted lines from a text file and writing the results to a new one:

```
f = open('messyParamsList.txt')
g = open('cleanerParamsList.txt','w')
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith('W'):
        g.write('%s\n' % line)
```

The original file is single-spaced, but the new file has an empty line between each line of text. How can I lose the empty lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not removing the newline from the input lines, so you shouldn't be adding one (`\n`) on output.

Answer (score 1):

Either strip the newlines off the lines you read or don't add new ones as you write it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
f = open('messyParamsList.txt')
g = open('cleanerParamsList.txt','w')
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith('W'):
        g.write(line)
```

Every line that you read from original file has `\n` (new line) character at the end, so do not add another one (right now you are adding one, which means you actually introduce empty lines).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the variable "line" already has a newline in it, but you're writing an additional newline with the g.write('%s**\n**' % line)

Answer (score 0):

line has a newline at the end.

Remove the \n from your write, or rstrip line.